# android retrieve data from web database through http request and PHP doesn't work

Tags: php, android, database

I tried to retrieve data from web database through Http request. But it doesn't work.
Only when the sql string include quotation marks, it will fails. Otherwise, it works fine.

When I debug, the return string is always like :

```
Warning:  mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/content/28/8269928/html/test.php on line 12 null (id=830020201688)
```

Android side code:

```
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("strSql", "select * from user where username='test'"));


    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://test.com/test.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
           System.out.println("Connectiong Error");
    }

    String js = "";
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "/n");
        }

        is.close();

        js = sb.toString();
        System.out.println("get = " + js);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
           System.out.println("Error converting to String");
    }
```

web server PHP code:

```
$myconn=mysql_connect("68.178.139.15", "username", "password");  
mysql_select_db("dbname");
mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");

$strSql = $_REQUEST['strSql'];

$result = mysql_query($strSql, $myconn);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $output[]=$row;
}

print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
```

Comment: echo $strSql before you use it, i bet it doesn't look right

Comment: solved, android side, URLEncoder.encode("select * from test where name='test'")

Comment: Is this code snipped supposed to be used on production environment? It is very insecure to run SQL queries directly from request without any filtering and authorization!

Answer (score 0):

solved

android side: 
URLEncoder.encode("select * from test where name=\'test\'")

php side: 
urldecode($_REQUEST['strSql']);

Comment: I really hope your code is only for testing, because passing unfiltered input from a request is dangerous as hell...

Comment: There are complete books written for this topic but you should never ever provide an SQL statement with a request. You should create an API where you only provide the "test" value and the SQL statement is created within your PHP. Some pointers: [PHP secure database](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and [Tips for secure PHP code](http://www.openlogic.com/wazi/bid/188021/Tips-for-Writing-Safe-Secure-PHP-Code) - Also consider simple searches on security topics.